# Basecamp Network Error only in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I'm having trouble using Basecamp in Chrome: it's started to error out most of the time (but not 100% of the time) with

```
Error 205 (net::ERR_CERT_UNABLE_TO_CHECK_REVOCATION): Unknown error.
```

I'm not having any problems logging in or using it in other browsers. I have a about a dozen Addons/ plugins, but I can't say this started right after installing a specific one. How can I debug this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be due to a bug in the newest update to Chrome (release 13th May 11' in Australia).

Hopefully it will be address soon, until then [here are some ways](http://www.computertipsfree.com/cant-access-paypal-error-205-neterr_cert_unable_to_check_revocation-unknown-error/) to get around the issue

**Edit**

FYI [here is the chromium ticket](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5313). It's from 09' but there's a recent addition from yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cache. This is due to the recent certificate update from MS.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference. The error is intermittent and I'm seeing it on other sites now (github) as well.